Conditionally Render A field in lightning-datatable
I am currently using a lighting-datatable.  Is there any way to conditionally render one of the fields in the javascript when I am setting the columns?  I know I could create multiple columns and then render the correct one on the page but was not sure if there is any way to change the actual column variable that get passed to the html to have only the columns I want.  In the below code, I would only want to pass the account field if the variable named isHif has a true value.
Here is the code.  Thank you!!
  const columns = [
  { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'urlLink', sortable: "true", type: 'url', initialWidth: 220,  
  typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: "Name" }, target: "_top" }, cellAttributes: {
    class: { fieldName: 'activeClass'}
  }},
  { label: 'Year', fieldName: 'Year__c', sortable: "true", initialWidth: 75,
  cellAttributes: {
    class: { fieldName: 'activeClass'}
  }},
  { label: 'Account', fieldName: 'Account__c', sortable: "true", initialWidth: 75,
  cellAttributes: {
    class: { fieldName: 'activeClass'}
  }},

